# How to debug d3 transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having issues with some d3 transitions. When an SVGCircleElement is clicked, I want the SVGTextElement in the same SVGGElement as the circle to fade, and once that has ended I want an information box to appear. Here is the relevant code.

```
// code where vizNode is defined

// Circle is the SVGCircleElement
var circle = vizNode.svgNode

var drag = d3.drag()
    .on('start', function () {
        dragStart(this)
    })
    .on('drag', dragMove)
    .on('end', dragEnd);

function dragStart(d) { //drag start logic }
function dragMove(d) { //drag move logic }
function dragEnd(d) { //drag end logic }

// Call drag method on SVGCircleElement
d3.select(circle).call(drag)

// g is the SVGGElement containing the SVGTextElement with the circle and class '.node-text'
var g = d3.select(circle.parentNode) 

g.selectAll('.node-text').transition()
    .duration(longFade)
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .on('start', function () {
        vizNode.infoBoxFadeIn = true
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        vizNode.infoBoxFadeIn = false
        drawNewInfoBox(vizNode)
    })

//drawNewInfoBox method
```

This works as expected at first. However, the user can drag the circles around using a different method. After this, the method above suddenly stops working - the .on('start) function is no longer being called.

Now, the big issue is that I have no idea how to debug this. All the relevant variables and objects stay the same, and the d3 selection that I'm trying to transition still exists after the dragging.

Does anybody have tips on how to approach this issue?

EDIT: Updated code to include the drag method

Comment: You'll probably need to provide a bit more code to reproduce the problem (like how are you doing the dragging?).  My off-the-cuff guess would be that your `start` event handler is getting overridden by the drag event handlers.

Comment: @Mark That sounds like it might be an explanation. I've added some more code snippets. Let me know if you need more information to make sense out of it. Thanks for the assistance!